# How to list post summaries by categories and keep theme formatting?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code lists the last whatever posts in all categories and uses the current theme for formatting the summary.

```html
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<div class="posts-loop">
<?php
   while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();
?>
<?php
/* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
 */
get_template_part('template-parts/' . $post_template);
?>

<?php
   }
?>
</div><!-- / .posts-loop -->
```

What I would like is to list posts by category but keep the formatting, so say I have the following categories:

- "Category 1" (slug is 'category1')
- "Category 2"
- "Category 3"

So what I envision is:

**Category 1**

[formatted summary of category 1 post 1 based on theme]

[formatted summary of category 2 post 1 based on theme]

[formatted summary of category 3 post 1 based on theme]

**Category 2**

[formatted summary of category 1 post 1 based on theme]

[formatted summary of category 2 post 1 based on theme]

[formatted summary of category 3 post 1 based on theme]

etc.

There is an example at [Forward Progressives](http://www.forwardprogressives.com/) that shows what I am trying to get. [My site](http://www.progressivesleading.com/) lists nicely for all posts.

I tried to modify the PHP code and tried a few plugins but nothing seems to work.

I tried the following PHP code, but that did not get me very far.

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 10, 'category' => 'features');
$latestPosts = get_posts($args);
if ($latestPosts)
{
    foreach ($latestPosts as $post)
    {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>

    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
     */
    get_template_part('template-parts/' . $post_template);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy enough with `get_categories()`, `WP_Query()` and a couple loops.

```
// Get all your categories
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'parent' => 0, /* we only want parent categories */
    'orderby' => 'name', /* order by category name, ascending */
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );

// Loop through each one
foreach( $categories as $category ) {

    ?><h2><?php echo( $category->name ); ?></h2><?php

    // Get some posts from each one
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $category->name ) );

    // Do all the stuff your theme already does    
    ?>

        <div class="posts-loop">
        <?php
           while ($query->have_posts()) {
              $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php
        /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part('template-parts/' . $post_template);
        ?>

        <?php
           }
        ?>
        </div><!-- / .posts-loop -->

    <?php

    // Reset query and loop again to next category, if there is one
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That worked! I was hitting my head against the wall for hours trying to figure this out.